# JQuery/Spring: Posting json object to spring controller not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, web

This is my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/{appId}/save.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String myFunction 
     (@PathVariable("appId") String id, @RequestBody Map<String, String> data1) {
                return "hello";
   }
```

This is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/app/${param.appID}/save.html',
                    data : JSON.stringify(myJsonData), 
                    dataType : "json",

                    success : function(data, textStatus,
                            xhr) {
                        var response = xhr.responseText;
                        if (response !== "hello") {
                            alert('sad');
                        } else {
                            alert('happy');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The problem is , this request never reaches the controller and gets stuck .
If I remove data and data1, things work fine. Can some help me with what am I doing wrong.

**Update**: Here's the error as shown by firebug

**415 Unsupported Media Type : The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ()**

Here is my json object

```
myJsonData= {
                        "data1" : $("input[name=key1]:checked").val(),
                        "data2" : $("input[name=key2]:checked").val(),
                        "data3" : $("input[name=key3]:checked").val()
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` is not necessary.

```
data : myJsonData,
```

is enough.

Comment: I have added the detailed error, it is same for both with and without stringify

Comment: @r15habh Do you have Jackson JSON Processor in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have the Jackson JSON Processor, but I found that I'm using <context:annotation-config/> instead of <mvc:annotation-driven/>, for some reason I can't use <mvc:annotation-driven/>, so I tried autowiring MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter but still the thing is not working

Comment: How have you wired the jacksonconverter ? I assume you defined DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter beans

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting `consumes="application/json"` in `@RequestMapping`